# phpmailer : Could not connect to SMTP host

Tags: php, phpmailer

This is sample code from phpmailer file. I edit some of code and it gives me error. i tried to change port number as well but gives me same error ever time

```
<?php
require("class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();                       // set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = "localhost";            // specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;               // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "mygmail@gmail.com";  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "password_is_correct"; // SMTP password

$mail->From = "mygmail@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "Harsh Patel";
$mail->AddAddress("mygmail@gmail.com");          // name is optional

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                         // set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->IsHTML(true);                            // set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = "Here is the subject";
$mail->Body    = "This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>";
$mail->AltBody = "This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients";

if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo "Message has been sent";
?>
```

Comment: You have based your code on an obsolete example and you're using an old version of PHPMailer. [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). You should also search before you post.

Answer (score 1):

Try with these changes as you are using gmail smtp

```
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; 
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
```